# Avaya Real-Time data Connection to PowerBI?

Tags: avaya

I was wondering if there was a method whereby I can get CMS data from Avaya to PowerBI in real time.

I read that this can be accomplished by Avayas custom real-time data connectors (RT_sockets/Generic-RTA etc), but those are all licensed.

Is there any other way (i.e. not needing a license) to pull in CMS data from Avaya, in real-time to Power BI?

Answer (score 0):

Informix will allow you to connect and pull data, but it's not real-time. It is near real-time and great for historical data analysis.

For real-time, I use the vbs scripting in Avaya CMS Supervisor (dump the returning data into a file or database). I've used this method to create nice reader boards in powerpoint and web apps.